# i have removed the .php extension using .htaccess but next part will not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

from dis line it will not work

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ blog.php?cat=$2
```

My url `http://localhost/Seo/blog.php?cat=SEO`

i want to convert it into `http://localhost/Seo/blog/cat/SEO`

extension are removed but next blog part is not working

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a "cat" in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/cat/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ blog.php?cat=$2
```

Since your URLs are going to look like *http //localhost/Seo/blog/**cat**/SEO*

Additionally, you'll want to put that rule **before** the rules that you already have.